# Unable to search media on the instagram API

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

I've been trying to use the "search" function of the media endpoint on the instagram API and it just answers a `500 internal error` with the message `"Oops, an error occurred."`.

Here's the request I send to the API:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=32.7157&lng=-117.165&distance=2000&access_token=xxx
```

I tried changing the distance, the latitude and longitude and choose another access_token, none of these changed a thing. Is it a problem with the current version of the API?

Comment: Having the same issue... can't figure out why this happens

Comment: @Maxence Henneron were you able to figure this out?

Comment: @manishKungwani It started to work again after some time (1 week..). I wish instagram had a real support